# Language changes in Android Application take place when running through Android Studio but do not work when app is downloaded from play store

Tags: java, android

I have added the strings.xml files for the languages I need. I use an alert dialog to switch language of my android application.

The language changes work when I run he application on my mobile or on my Virtual Device through Android Studio without any problem but when I package the application and upload it on Play Store, they do not work.

When the application is downloaded from playstore, only the timepicker is translated in other languages and none of the other text.

I have written a setLocale function to change the language of the application which is called from OnCreate and language picker functions.

I store the language in Shared Preferences so that the option is retained when app is closed.

```
OnCreate(){
  SharedPreferences pref = MainActivity.this.getSharedPreferences("languageSelectionMode", MODE_PRIVATE);
        languagetoLoad = pref.getString("languageSelectionNameTemp","en");}
setLocale(languagetoLoad);
```

this is the setLocale function

```
 public void setLocale(String lang) {

        if (!"".equals(lang) && !config.locale.getLanguage().equals(lang)) {

            Locale locale = new Locale(lang);
            Locale.setDefault(locale);
            Configuration conf = new Configuration(config);
            conf.locale = locale;
            getBaseContext().getResources().updateConfiguration(conf, getBaseContext().getResources().getDisplayMetrics());

            SharedPreferences pref = MainActivity.this.getSharedPreferences("languageSelectionMode", MODE_PRIVATE);
            SharedPreferences.Editor editor = pref.edit();

            editor.putString("languageSelectionNameTemp",lang);
            editor.apply();

            finish();
            overridePendingTransition(0, 0);
            startActivity(getIntent());
            overridePendingTransition(0, 0);
        }
```

function where i change the language.

```
SharedPreferences pref = MainActivity.this.getSharedPreferences("languageSelectionMode", MODE_PRIVATE);

                int languageLoaded =  pref.getInt("languageSelectionId",0);
                //Convert ListArray to Array ..... profileNames.toArray()
                builder.setSingleChoiceItems(languageArray, languageLoaded, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {


                        switch(which){
                            case 0:
                                languageChoice = "en";
                                languageChoiceId = 0;

                                break;
                            case 1:
                                languageChoice = "mr";
                                languageChoiceId = 1;

                                break;
                            case 2:
                                languageChoice = "hi";
                                languageChoiceId = 2;

                                break;
                            default:
                                languageChoice = "en";
                                languageChoiceId = 0;

                        }
                    }
                });

                builder.setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {SharedPreferences pref = MainActivity.this.getSharedPreferences("languageSelectionMode", MODE_PRIVATE);
                        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = pref.edit();
            editor.putInt("languageSelectionId", languageChoiceId);
            editor.apply();
                        setLocale(languageChoice);

                    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution somewhere. The app wasn't translating on production because of Android Bundle issues. Normal apk was working fine.

Added the following lines in gradle file and it works fine.

```
bundle{
      language{
          enableSplit = false
      }
  }
```